# Authorising the same Google Accounts in multiple instances in an app

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I have an app that allows the user to connect their Google account to pull in events from their Google Calendar. For example, for the user account john@example.com the user can connect his john@gmail.com account and enable the sync with Google Calendar. This part is all good.

The problem is let's say the user also has another account on the app using the email johnny@example2.com, when he connects his john@gmail.com to the second account, the access token would become invalidated for the first account. So the Google Calendar sync will only work for the second account.

How can I avoid this behaviour and allow multiple instances of the same Google Account to be authorised on the same app? One app that comes to mind is Zapier where it allows us to connect the same Google Account across different Zapier accounts without the previous connection being severed.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a neat solution to this problem. The only solution I have found is to manage a single connection in a connection table and associate that connection with multiple user accounts on your end.